# PlayFramework 2.2.x: correct way to detect request's accepted content type

Tags: playframework, content-type

I need to check if a specific content type is accepted by the request. My first naïve implementation was:

```
if (request.acceptedTypes.contains(JSON)) …
```

that systematically returns `false`.

The actual one that works is:

```
if (request.acceptedTypes.exists(_.mediaSubType == "json")) …
```

but I found it a bit ugly (and not precise of course).

What's the right way to perform this check.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this? http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaContentNegotiation

```
val list = Action { implicit request =>
  val items = Item.findAll
  render {
    case Accepts.Html() => Ok(views.html.list(items))
    case Accepts.Json() => Ok(Json.toJson(items))
  }
}
```